# How I can add td to css style for inputs and its label?

Tags: html, css

I want to add some inputs in a table for alignment need.
But the style did not work and stopped.
How I can add td to this css style.
For example, something like this:

```
                <p>Stuff you like:</p>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="css3">CSS3</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="css3" id="css3" /> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table><!-- It does not work-->


            <p><input type="checkbox" value="HTML5" id="html5" />
<label for="html5">HTML5</label></p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" value="JavaScript" id="javascript" />
<label for="javascript">JavaScript</label></p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" value="Other" id="other" /> 
<label for="other">Other</label></p>
<!--But it work-->

/*CSS*/
input:hover + label, input:focus + label,
input + label:hover, input:focus + label{
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
color: #2C7AD0; 
}
```

Comment: you want to do this with javascript(jquery) or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the table markup, the `label` element does not match any of your selectors. The `label` and `input` elements aren’t siblings at all. You need something rather different. The following works, with the usual CSS Caveats, for the “hover” part:

```
tr:hover label { ... }
```

Regarding the “focus” part, I’m afraid you can’t use pure CSS due to structural limitations: you cannot make the focused state of an element affect the rendering of an element before it. You would need to use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your HTML code? How does it look like? What you try won't bring you the results. Do you put the input into a label tag or upside down? This is how your CSS code looks like. And the "+" definitely is used only in javascript, not CSS.

As you did not post your HTML yet, I can just guess, but your CSS should rather look like:

```
input:hover label, input:focus label,
input label:hover, input:focus label {
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
color: #2C7AD0; 
}
```

OR most likely

UPDATE (use this, this should work):

```
input, input:hover, input:focus, label,
label:hover, label:focus {
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
color: #2C7AD0; 
}
```

Comment: @Mohamed Reheem: yes, thank you for posting the HTML! you see, your input tags and your label tags are not inside each other, so they are not parent-child related. Therefore you just need to separate them with a comma, as they are on the same level... got it? So, the second CSS in my post is the right one for you... let me know, if it worked for you! :)

Comment: @Mohamed Reheem: pls see the update in the second CSS example

Comment: it does not work :(
if you test the original css style you will feel the difference

Answer (score 0):

check this code using jquery

```
var option = {
  x:      1, 
  y:      2, 
  radius: 3,
  color:  "#ccff00"
}

$("#yourelems").textShadow( option );
$("#yourelems").css("color","red");
```